# Use GridView/ListView inside StackPanel/ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, winui-3

I have a page with multiple controls similar to this vertically:

```
TextBlock
Some Images
TextBlock
Some Images
ListView
```

The height of TextBlock and Images exceed the height of the screen.
Therefore, I need to put a scrollviewer like this:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Grid>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text=...></TextBlock>
          <Image Grid.Row="1" Source=...></Image>
          <ListView Grid.Row="2"></ListView>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

It leads to a problem as the scrollviewer will defeat the virtualization of the listview (ListView has ~200 items).

Is there anyway I can put ListView as the last element of Grid that:

- Has fast performance
- Display all rows (Don't want to set MaxHeight of the ListView, as 2 ScrollViewers will be confusing)
- The page has only 1 vertical Scrollbar

Answer (score 0):

Use `ListView` as the root of the page and leverage [`ListView.Header`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.header?view=winrt-22621) for the top scrolling content.

```xml
<ListView>
   <ListView.Header>
      <StackPanel>
          <TextBlock />
          <Image />
      </StackPanel>
    </ListView.Header>
</ListView>
```

Alternatively, you could also do it using a combination of [`ListView.HeaderTemplate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.headertemplate?view=winrt-22621#windows-ui-xaml-controls-listviewbase-headertemplate) and `ListView.Header`.